# Use R list as dictionary to replace strings

Tags: r

I have a list containing the results of a factor analysis.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = rep(1:2, 50),
                 var2 = c(1:50),
                 var3 = rep(1:25, 2),
                 var4 = rnorm(50),
                 var5 = rnorm(50))
fa.fit <- stats::factanal(df, factors=2,
                          scores = "regression",
                          rotation = "varimax")
```

I also have a list containing variable names and variable labels:

```
var_labels <- list("var1" = "variable 1",
                     "var5" = "variable 5",
                     "var3" = "variable 3",
                     "var4" = "variable 4",
                     "var2" = "variable 2")
```

I want to use the list to assign variable labels to the row names of `fa.fit$loadings`. Is there a way to use the list as a dictionary so the matching variable names are labeled correctly?

I tried this:

```
rownames(fa.fit$loadings) <- var_labels

rownames(fa.fit$loadings)
[1] "variable 1" "variable 5" "variable 3" "variable 4" "variable 2"
```

But my desired output is this:

```
[1] "variable 1" "variable 2" "variable 3" variable 4" "variable 5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset the `list` with the `row.names` and `unlist` the `list` to be assigned

```
row.names(fa.fit$loadings) <- unlist(var_labels[row.names(fa.fit$loadings)])
```

-output

```
fa.fit$loadings

Loadings:
           Factor1 Factor2
variable 1          0.161 
variable 2  0.995         
variable 3  0.506         
variable 4          0.997 
variable 5  0.198         

               Factor1 Factor2
SS loadings      1.287   1.036
Proportion Var   0.257   0.207
Cumulative Var   0.257   0.465
```